# AWS RDS How to set up a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a Java application running on successfully on `Amazon Web Services Elastic Beanstalk`.

I am trying to set up `MySQL`. I have created a DB Instance as you can see:

[image]

[image]

**Question 1:**

How do I connect my Java App to the Database?

I have the following code (after viewing [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console)):

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        // Openshift
//      String host = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST");
//      String port = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT");
//      String username = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME");
//      String password = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD");

        // AWS
        String host = System.getenv("RDS_HOSTNAME");
        String port = System.getenv("RDS_PORT");
        String username = System.getenv("RDS_USERNAME");
        String password = System.getenv("RDS_PASSWORD");
        String dbname = System.getenv("RDS_DB_NAME");

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        if (host == null) {
            dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url")); 
            dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
            dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        } else {
            //dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/");
            // Openshift
            //dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.dbname"));
            // AWS
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbname);
            dataSource.setUsername(username);
            dataSource.setPassword(password);
            System.out.println("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbname+", username: "+username+", password: "+password);
        }

        return dataSource;
    }
```

(p.s. the commented out code works on OpenShifts server)

But I get the following:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire
>   JDBC Connection
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)

**Question 2:**

From an existing database, in `MySQL Workbench`, I have exported sql scripts to create a schema and tables, and then populate them.  How do I import this into the `AWS RDS MySQL` database?

**More info:**

Server Logs:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat8/localhost.2017-02-21.log
-------------------------------------
21-Feb-2017 14:42:51.133 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
21-Feb-2017 14:42:51.737 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'rest'
21-Feb-2017 14:57:36.680 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [rest] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:258)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2323)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:67)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.jobs.spring.controller.CategoryRESTService.findAllCategorys(CategoryRESTService.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

21-Feb-2017 15:09:21.090 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'rest'
21-Feb-2017 15:09:38.729 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
21-Feb-2017 15:09:39.329 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'rest'
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

I also added rules to open it for everyone, but still get the same error:

[image]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384751/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused-connection-refused?noredirect=1#comment71918710_42384751

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with your database and the security group.
Hover to the "i" icon next to the Cluster Endpoint.

A popup will appear with the security groups.
Hit the first default link and you will be redirected to the security groups configuration. 
Then you have to edit the security group and add an inbound rule in order to include your local ip.

Keep in mind that this will work only if your rds is on a public subnet.

This link is pretty [helpful](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-cannot-connect/) for troubleshooting.

More information on [security groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look.

Comment: Thanks. But I see there is already a rule by default that has my IP. I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk running Tomcat that needs to access the MySQL database. It looks like it is already configured to have that IP.  I will add a screen print above.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384751/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused-connection-refused?noredirect=1#comment71918710_42384751